# Vanilla JS - function to hide and show a div by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue; where when I click a button that takes the value from a drop-down list, it is supposed to show the div assigned to his matching value.

So far, my code do as intended, it shows the corresponding div, but then it reverts and hides it back 3 seconds after. It could be a simple mistake, your help is appreciated.

At the head:

```
    var e = document.getElementById("graph_req_ID");
    var indexValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    function getGraphReq(){       
    if (strValue == "Default") {
        graph3.style.display = "block";

    } else {
        graph3.style.display = "none";
    }             
    }
```

My button:

```
    <button onclick="getGraphReq()"></button>
```

The hidden div:

```
    <div id="graph3">
         <h4>this content should show after clicking the button</h4>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getGraphReq(){ 
 
  var e = document.getElementById("graph_req_ID");
  var indexValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  if (strValue == "Default") {
    graph3.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    graph3.style.display = "none";
  }             
}
```

```html
 <select id="graph_req_ID">
  <option value="Default">Default</option>
  <option value="Default">foo</option>
</select>
<button onclick="getGraphReq()">Click me</button>
 <div id="graph3">
  <h4>this content should show after clicking the button</h4>
</div>
```

I moved those variables into the function. Then when you execute the function it will assign correct values to the variables. Is this the expected output you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darshana! Works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the issue with your code, but is that the intended behaviour?

```js
var e = document.getElementById("graph_req_ID");
var indexValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

function getGraphReq() {
  var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  if (strValue == "Default") {
    graph3.style.display = "block";

  } else {
    graph3.style.display = "none";
  }
}

getGraphReq();
```

```html
<select id='graph_req_ID'>
  <option value='Default'>Default</option>
  <option value='Other' selected>Other</option>
</select>
<button onclick="getGraphReq()">getGraphReq</button>
<div id="graph3">
  <h4>this content should show after clicking the button</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It works by moving all 3 variables inside the function!

Answer (score 0):

If the element should not be visible onload and only by the click event then:

```
<div id="graph3" style="display:none">
```

Your code worked for me. Possibly something else in the file causing your issue. Hard to tell with what you posted.